# Eloquent Lookup Tables and Model Creation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

So I've been working on a project for a few weeks now and have just picked up Laravel because of it (definitely a fan so far!) I ran into a bit of an issue today though:

I have an application that needs to make requests to different APIs based on credentials our user provides. All these tasks are meant to provide the same service but in different ways which brought me to think there should probably be a good Object Oriented approach to this. I've come up with some ideas using both a strategy pattern and a factory pattern, but they seem to be inelegant next to Eloquent's simple layout.

Just as a better example of what I'm talking about, I have users who can provide either a username, email, or phone number (depending on the requirements of their selected API). I've made 4 tables so far which look like this:

`users: id, username, passhash`

`api_list: id, api_name, api_table_name, logo_url`

`user_api_lookup: id, user_id, api_list_id`

`api1_table: id, user_api_lookup_id, email`

Does this look like the right setup to do what I'm trying?

**Update:**
I should have probably mentioned what my application looks like as well

Each user has many API integrations and these are accessed with Eloquent's relation helpers

```
class User
{
...
    public function rewardMethods()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(APIIntegration::class);
    }
...
}
```

hopefully that clarifies a bit

Comment: So an API will require one of those: *username, email or phone number*? Or it can require more than one of those? Does this `api1_table` is for one api and the next api will have its own database table?

Comment: So far we've only dealt with APIs that needed 1 of those.
And yeah, that's what I was thinking for the `apiN_table`s

Comment: this is not a good approach, imho, when using relational db like mysql.

Comment: Is there a way that would work better? I've been looking at the laravel documentation for something similar, but haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please read this first.**

> This example assumes the following statements:
>
> - An API can have multiple credentials.
> - An User can have multiple APIs.
>
> That doesn't mean that you won't be able to support **one to one** relation, though.

I have created a simple example of a good approach which can support N APIs and avoiding having a separate database table for each API.

Here are the database tables.

`apis` table will be equivalent of your `api_list`, which will hold the information about the API. In my example (as I said it's really simple) I have added a column `name` only.

```
CREATE TABLE `apis` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I made a simple `users` table just for this example:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then I made a new table called `credentials` which will hold all credential types an API can have. For example: **Username**, **Email**, **Phone Number**. `name` column will hold human friendly name of the credential.

```
CREATE TABLE `credentials` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I went for the approach which will cover `apis` that have more than one required `credential`. That's why I needed a pivot table between `apis` and `credentials`.

```
CREATE TABLE `api_credential` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `api_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `credential_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Next table I needed is a table that holds which `api` an `user` has. This is the equivalent of your `user_api_lookup` table.

```
CREATE TABLE `api_user` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `api_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And the last table is what will hold the actual credentials `api_credential_user`:

```
CREATE TABLE `api_credential_user` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `api_credential_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `value` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Then we will need to generate (at least I user `artisan` for this) our models and set the relationship between them.

```
php artisan make:model Api
php artisan make:model ApiCredential
php artisan make:model ApiCredentialUser
php artisan make:model ApiUser
php artisan make:model Credential
```

The `User` model comes with Laravel's installation.

The `Api`  model looks like this:
(*I added comments on each relationship*)

```
class Api extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'apis';

    /**
     * As I said an API might have multiple credential types/fields.
     */
    public function credentials()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Credential');
    }

    /**
     * This will return all users that have a specific api attached.
     */
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

`Credential` model:

```
class Credential extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'credentials';

    /**
     * Get all apis this credential belongs to.
     */
    public function apis()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Api');
    }

    public function apiCredential() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ApiCredential');
    }
}
```

`ApiCredential` model:

```
class ApiCredential extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'api_credential';

    /**
     * Those are defined in the sake of consistency.
     * Probably will not be used.
     */
    public function api()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Api');
    }

    /**
     * Those are defined in the sake of consistency.
     * Probably will not be used.
     */
    public function credential()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Credential');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ApiCredentialUser');
    }
}
```

`ApiCredentialUser` model:

```
class ApiCredentialUser extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'api_credential_user';
}
```

`User` model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function apis()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Api');
    }
}
```

Dummy data for demo purposes:

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, 'test@user.com'), (NULL, 'test2@user.com');
INSERT INTO `credentials` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'phone_number'), (NULL, 'username'), (NULL, 'email');
INSERT INTO `apis` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 'Github API'), (NULL, 'StackOverflow API'), (NULL, 'Twitter API'), (NULL, 'Facebook API'), (NULL, 'LinkedIn API');
INSERT INTO `api_credential` (`id`, `api_id`, `credential_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1'), (NULL, '2', '2'),(NULL, '3', '3'), (NULL, '4', '1'),(NULL, '5', '2');
INSERT INTO `api_user` (`id`, `api_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '1'), (NULL, '2', '2');
INSERT INTO `api_credential_user` (`id`, `api_credential_id`, `value`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '0700-1111-2222'), (NULL, '2', 'myUsername');
```

Sample usages of those relations:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    //Fetching all users (dummy data)
    $user_1 = App\User::find(1);
    $user_2 = App\User::find(2);

    //To list every user's apis
    echo '<h3>User: ' . $user_1->email . '</h3>';
    echo 'Apis attached: <br />';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($user_1->apis as $api) {
        echo '<li>' . $api->name . '</li>';
        //You can get required credentials per api.
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($api->credentials as $credential) {
            //And for every credential you can get user's value.
            echo '<li><b>Name:</b> ' . $credential->name . ' - <b>User value</b>: ' . $credential->apiCredential->user->value . '</li>';

        }
        echo '</li></ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';


    //To list every user's apis
    echo '<h3>User: ' . $user_2->email . '</h3>';
    echo 'Apis attached: <br />';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ($user_2->apis as $api) {
        echo '<li>' . $api->name . '</li>';
        //You can get required credentials per api.
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($api->credentials as $credential) {
            //And for every credential you can get user's value.
            echo '<li><b>Name:</b> ' . $credential->name . ' - <b>User value</b>: ' . $credential->apiCredential->user->value . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</li></ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';

    //To list all apis
    echo '<h3>All apis:</h3>';
    $apis = \App\Api::all();
    foreach ($apis as $api) {
        echo $api->name . '<br />';
    }

    //To list all credentials:
    echo '<h3>All credentials:</h3>';
    $credentials = \App\Credential::all();
    foreach ($credentials as $credential) {
        echo $credential->name . '<br />';
    }
});
```

Which with the dummy data provided above will give this: [screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/1ab83deddcbe44ffbe0ac19e9305bc9e.png).

Comment: After implementing this example, I found it all a little confusing, but that's not to say it's not a very good way to do it.

Instead I looked up some tutorials about polymorphism in eloquent and found these links:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships

https://adamwathan.me/2015/09/03/pushing-polymorphism-to-the-database/

I've gone ahead and used those which have worked out pretty well so far

Comment: @AlexC If yours seems to work better, you should self answer your question and accept that answer. :)